# Difference between calling a python script by terminal and by PHP? Where is the Error?

Tags: php, python, import, terminal, exec

I have a PHP script, that calls a python script by

```
$call_python = "python ../python/lp_3.py ".$author;
$python_output = Null;
$mystring = exec($call_python, $output_python);
```

This produces me an error in the log:

```
$ vi logs/error_log shows
....
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "../python/lp_3.py", line 14, in <module>
        import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

If I do `python python/lp_3.py` in the terminal everything is fine. What do I miss?

### Edit:

After the suggestion of @S.Lott I had a look at the variables `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` both in the terminal and in PHP.

In the terminal:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

As you can see, `PYTHONPATH` is empty.

In PHP:

```
echo getenv("PYTHONPATH"); // NOTHING
echo getenv("PATH"); // /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Perhaps I should mention that the first two lines in my python script are

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
```

I am open for suggestions. =)

### Edit2:

I checked every installed python version on my mac. I found out, that python2.7 has no MySQLdb installed. Is there a way to tell PHP **not** to use python2.7 and to use e.g. python2.6 instead? I tryed toying with `setenv()` in PHP but I couldn't figure out how to use it properly, and I don't even know if this is the right approach.

Comment: In PHP, your `PYTHONPATH` is different from in the shell.  Or, worse, the entire `PATH` is different and you have multiple Pythons.  You need to display the `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables at the command prompt and in PHP.  There may be other things, but that's a start.

Comment: If I may ask, how do I do that in PHP?

Comment: Yeah...I just did a test on my system and it works without specifying PYTHONPATH from PHP.  I'm betting on multiple installs here, one without MySQLdb.

Comment: @Aufwind: That's a separate question.  Step 1. Search.  Step 2.  If that doesn't help, Ask.

Comment: @Aufwind Also be careful with your current working directory, if your importing modules relative to your lp_3.py file.

Comment: check what is the user that is executing your PHP scripts (www-data?)

Comment: @Andrea: The PHP script is on a XAMPP Server at the moment. It is executed after a user added some content to a form and hit submit... Is that what you mean?

Comment: just do ps aux  to see what is the unix user running the php scripts or xampp

Comment: Just making sure... your `$author` variable *is* adequately sanitized, right?

Comment: @a3_nm Yes, it is just a string which should go as a parameter.

Comment: @AJ: I think your guess may point into the right direction. But I still don't know how to solve this. :-)

Comment: @Aufwind - in your PHP code, you're just calling "python", and letting PHP decide which version of Python to use.  Use an explicit path to a **specific** Python binary, e.g. `/usr/bin/python2.6`.  You need to know the exact path to the version of Python that has MySQLdb installed.

Comment: @AJ: That did the Job, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your PHP code, you're just calling "python", and letting PHP decide which version of Python to use. Use an explicit path to a specific Python binary, (e.g. /usr/bin/python2.6).

You need to know the exact path to the version of Python that has MySQLdb installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$call_python = "/opt/local/bin/python2.6 ../python/lp_3.py ".$author;
$python_output = Null;
$mystring = exec($call_python, $output_python);
```

did the job. Like @AJ pointed out, I had to tell python which version to chose. I chose a version where MySQLdb was available and all was fine.