# MySQLdb import error when calling python script from PHP

Tags: php, python-3.6, mysql-python

I am on Ubuntu16, **python3.6** is installed through anaconda distribution.

I have successfully installed MySQLdb module and it works fine when called (say) from the terminal. However, when I try to execute the same python script from PHP (version 7) using

```
$tmp = exec("python script_name.py", $input_parameters );
```

I get the following error message

**ImportError: No module named MySQLdb**

Any ideas why this might happen? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check whether you are using the right python installation. Ubuntu comes with its own.

Comment: You can check with `system("which python");`

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer, thanks for the reply! the default version is correct (it's 3.6), however  since $PYTHONPATH was empty ( anaconda  is added to path, so python comes from there) PHP was confusing the version of Python . Anyways, after more googling I found this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051693/difference-between-calling-a-python-script-by-terminal-and-by-php-where-is-the (and your comment is also in that direction) , which resolved my problem. One needs to specify the full path of python in exec command, that's it.