# php script error while executing python script and importing webdriver from selenium

Tags: php, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am executing python script from php which is importing webdriver from selenium but I am getting error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/www/html/spreadsheet/script.py", line 10, in from selenium
>   import webdriver ImportError: No module named selenium

Selenium is installed and python script is working perfectly from bash. i have also run it from sudo but still getting the same error.

my php script is

```
$dir = __DIR__;
$command = "sudo -u www-data python ".$dir."/script.py 2>&1";

$pid = popen( $command,"r");

while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 usleep(200000);
}
pclose($pid);
```

and in script.py i am getting eror

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import os.path
```

so i am getting error while importing webdriver.

Comment: i am using ubuntu and i have added  www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
in /etc/sudoers to give sudo access to php.You can remove sudo -u www-data and try running with python ".$dir."/script.py 2>&1 only

Comment: And you tried this via sudo from console?

Comment: yes script is fine, i already mentioned in question. with sudo and without sudo its fine form console but from php it is throwing error for module not found

Comment: It might be an environment problem not having set some variables. Did you try to start python wrapped into `bash -c`?

Comment: if there is any environment problem then it should throw error on console as well. standalone python execution from console is not throwing error and working perfectly so there is no problem for env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186958/discussion-between-hassaan-and-quasimodos-clone).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between calling a python script by terminal and by PHP? Where is the Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051693/difference-between-calling-a-python-script-by-terminal-and-by-php-where-is-the)

Comment: Actually the situation is same as you identified, but the solution didn't helped me. As i have given path variables but still not working. Then finally i copied selenium folder in my php root project and then it starts working fine.

Comment: You should anwer your own question describing all the analysis and steps you have done and accept this. So other people looking for such an issue could get a solution. StackOverflow is meant to be a knowledge database.

Answer (score 1):

Is the selenium module installed? if not installed it using 
pip install selenium --> for Python 2.7 and above
pip3 install selenium --> for Python3.^ and above